# java.io.File.<init>(File,String) JDK version dependent

Tags: java, file, java-8, java-io, java-9

It's looks like **java.io.File.(File, String)** is JDK version dependent.
Code example was run on Windows 10.

Code example:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String path = "C:\\Workspace\\project";
    File file = null;
    for (String part : path.split("\\\\")) {
        file = new File(file, part);
    }
    System.out.println(file);
    // prints "C:Workspace\project" for JDK 9+
    // prints "C:\Workspace\project" for JDK 8
}
```

Could you please address is there any known issue or solution for the case

Comment: The new behavior seems to be the correct one. `C:` means the current directory on drive C and when you append `Workspace` it should become the relative `C:Workspace`. If you start with `C:\\` then you should get the other result.

Comment: I wonder if that's where the [JEP 326: Raw String Literals](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/326) *(#File Paths Example)* can really be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java 9, the `WinNTFileSystem` class (FileSystem implementation for windows) changed.
It probably solves a issue which the way the class considers what a absolute path is.  I didn't find a bug that exactly specifies this one but some are close to.

`File.isAbsolute()` states :

> On Microsoft Windows systems, a pathname is absolute if its prefix is
>   a drive specifier followed by "\", or if its prefix is "\\".

So according to the specification, for the following:

```
File x = new File("C:", "Workspace"); 
System.out.println(x.isAbsolute()); // not absolute according to the spec

File xx = new File("C:\\", "Workspace");
System.out.println(xx.isAbsolute());

File xxx = new File("\\\\Workspace");
System.out.println(xxx.isAbsolute());
```

we expect :

> false
>   true
>   true

But we get  :

> true
>   true
>   true

From Java 9 it produces the expected result.

The problem is that before Java 9 a path without `\` is all the same considered as an absolute path :

```
File x = new File("C:", "Workspace");
System.out.println(x.isAbsolute()); // true
```

While that this should not be the case.

Concretely, the main changes concern the `resolve(String parent, String child)` method of the `WinNTFileSystem` class.
Before, `resolve()` resolved the abstract path by adding a slash between the parent and the child for any child path that doesn't start with a slash.
From Java 9, `resolve()` doesn't add a slash any longer between the parent and the child if the parent is a drive.

Here is the [change](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/777356696811/src/java.base/windows/classes/java/io/WinNTFileSystem.java#l261) :

```
boolean isDirectoryRelative =
    pn == 2 && isLetter(parent.charAt(0)) && parent.charAt(1) == ':';

if (child.charAt(childStart) == slash || isDirectoryRelative) {
    theChars = new char[strlen];             ^-------- this one was added from Java 9
    parent.getChars(0, parentEnd, theChars, 0);
    child.getChars(childStart, cn, theChars, parentEnd);
} else {
    theChars = new char[strlen + 1];
    parent.getChars(0, parentEnd, theChars, 0);
    theChars[parentEnd] = slash;
    child.getChars(childStart, cn, theChars, parentEnd + 1);
}
```

**Consequences**

About your question :

> Could you please address is there any known issue or solution for the
>   case

The difference between the two JDK versions matters. 
It concerns both the value of the abstract pathname's normalized pathname (`File.getPath()`) and the value of the absolute path `File.getAbsolutePath()` as now `new File("C:", "Workspace")` produces a relative path.

If your application relies on `File.getPath()` to do some parsing on that, it could have a distinct behavior and create some issues.
To have a portable code between the JDK versions, any parsing on the resolved path should consider as optional the `\` just after the Windows drive.
In this way `C:\` and `C:` would be handled in the same way.

If your application relies on `File.getAbsolutePath()`, it could also have some surprises from Java 9 as now the path that is relative will be resolved against the filesystem (before as an absolute path this just returned itself).
So instead, you should so probably use `File.getPath()` to not resolve the path against the file system.

Answer (score 4):

Addition to @david answer,

It was a **[bug#8153250](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8153250)**, which was address and fixed version is available `JDK 9 b153`.

Comment: Should this be the duplicate of SO question linked in the Bug you've shared? Seems like the proper implementation is what the fix implies in JDK-10 or above.

Comment: @nullpointer Even I think, it is duplicate of same question. There are similar issue which is related to same bug (which actually mentioned in same bug) are fixed in JDK10.

Answer (score 2):

As @davidxxx pointed out `getAbsoluteFile` or `getAbsolutePath` on the initial File instance is the same for Java8 and Java9. If you however decide to use this initial File to create a new File you'd probably be surprised about the differences - at least I was.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File file = new File((File)null, "C:");
    System.out.println(file);
    System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile());

    System.out.println("----");

    file = new File(file, "Windows");
    System.out.println(file);
    System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile());
}
```

If you execute the above program with Java 8 and 9 `file` will point to completely different folders after the second assignment. As the initial file is the same for Java8 and 9 I'd actually consider this to be a bug in Java 8 (and before probably).

Output Java 8:

> C:
>   C:\ws\PLAYGROUND\test
>   ---- 
>   C:\Windows
>   C:\Windows

Output Java 9:

> C:
>   C:\ws\PLAYGROUND\test
>   ---- 
>   C:Windows
>   C:\ws\PLAYGROUND\test\Windows